# how can i switch from RTL to LTR when language changes?

Tags: html, right-to-left

i'm setting up a new template, and i want to support many language like Arabic & English when user hit the language button, where do i need to set RTL and LTR in my template how can i do it ?

```
{
  "base": "semantic\\",
  "paths": {
    "source": {
      "config": "src/theme.config",
      "definitions": "src/definitions/",
      "site": "src/site/",
      "themes": "src/themes/"
    },
    "output": {
      "packaged": "dist/",
      "uncompressed": "dist/components/",
      "compressed": "dist/components/",
      "themes": "dist/themes/"
    },
    "clean": "dist/"
  },
  "permission": false,
  "autoInstall": false,
  "rtl": false,
  "version": "2.4.2"
}
```

Comment: set the `dir` attribute to `ltr` in your `html` tag. something like this: `<html dir="ltr"> ... </html>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rtlcss` project that has a cdn with both directions.

`https://cdn.rtlcss.com/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.rtl.css`

and

`https://cdn.rtlcss.com/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.css`